# React: Delete one children without rendering the parent again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent-child

I have a `parent component` where a list of `children` gets displayed. The children are literature `Cards` and each `card` has a `delete button`. When I click on the delete button the entire parent and children gets rendered again and so so entire page gets refreshed. So If I am e.g. at the bottom of the literature card list (e.g. 900 literature cards) and delete the last literature card, the page gets refreshed and because of that I'm at the beginning of the page and not at the end of the page (or wherever I was before). This is kind of annoying because I have to scroll down the entire page after deleting a child.

This is basically my parent code:

```
class ProjectLiterature extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      literatureEntries: [],
}}
getLiteratureEntries(){
axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/getLiterature`)
    .then(res => {

      const literatureEntries = res.data;
      this.setState({ literatureEntries })

    })
    }

deleteLiteratureEntry(id) {
    axios.delete("http://127.0.0.1:5000/deleteLiterature", {
      params: {
        id
      }
    })
      .then(res => {

        // get current literature entries after deleting one file
        this.getLiteratureEntries();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

render() {
    const literatureEntries = this.state.literatureEntries
    return (
       {  literatureEntries.map((literature, index) => 
             return (
             <Literature literature={literature} key={literature._id}
             deleteLiteratureEntry={this.deleteLiteratureEntry.bind(this)} 
             project_name={this.state.projectName}/>
            )
          })
   }
)}
```

and this is basically my child component:

```
export default class Literature extends Component {

    render() {
        const literature = this.props.literature
        return (
              <Card>
              <CardHeader>             
                   {literature.title}
                  <Button className="float-right" onClick={() => 
                       this.props.deleteLiteratureEntry(literature._id}
                   </Button>                       
              </CardHeader>    
              <CardBody>
                 ...
              </CardBody>
              </Card>
)}}
```

So is there anything I could do that maybe not the entire list gets rendered again?

Comment: what does your deleteLiteratureEntry method look like?

Comment: can we see the code for deleting the element?

Comment: thanks for your comment. I added the delete method

Comment: Does your `getLiteratureEntries` clear the state at any point, prior to setting the fetched data ?

Comment: I also added my entire getLiteratureEntries method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you are refetching your list after you delete. so instead just remove it manually instead of refetching the whole list

```
deleteLiteratureEntry(id) {
    axios.delete("http://127.0.0.1:5000/deleteLiterature", {
      params: {
        id
      }
    })
      .then(res => {

        let newList = this.state.literatureEntries.filter(item => item.id !== id);
        this.setState({ literatureEntries: newList )}
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

Comment: what does this.state.filter(item...) exactly do? Is item a literature entry? So if the ID of a literature entry is stored in the variable "_id" I should do: "this.state.filter(item => item._id !== id);"

Comment: yes exactly, this is used to remove the literature entry

Comment: The problem isn't with refetching data, if the parent's state change it will re-render. Besides, refetching data is always a good idea to avoid having stale data if the list may be edited by other users. (add a card to favorite and it was deleted by another user for example)

Comment: they didnt post all the code, but refetching data isnt "always" good specially when you lazy load items and could potentially reload hundreds of items. Yes doing this will cause a re-render but if you have correct keys you can avoid updates, react will just go through reconciliation and should be fairly quick even with many records. can this be optimized YES, but this is a simple answer. @Incepter

Comment: Also note @Incepter if you re-render a component in react it will not update the scroll position...

Comment: Agree it isn't always good but loading hundreds of items is really not good, this is what pagination is made for. The question states that they are using good keys (the id), and also, you won't avoid updates by setting keys. If a parent render, its children will also render unless memo or shouldComponentUpdate decides the contrary. and there are many parts missing of the code we can't help with the scroll matter

Comment: yes this is what pagination is made for. there are things you can do like virtualization. But yes you will avoid updates to the dom BUT react will still go through reconciliation. also making each record memoized has a very large overhead and i would not recommend that. and if you are virtualizing the list it will be a quick update since only the ones in view will be rendered. @Incepter

Comment: I've tried it but I'm getting an error in the console: "TypeError: _this11.state.filter is not a function" at this line:"let newList = this.state.filter(item => item._id !== id);"

Comment: @Joey reconciliation comes after render.

Comment: this.state. literatureEntries.filter not this.state.filter @Till

Comment: @Till state does not have a filter function, you have to do : `this.state.literatureEntries.filter` I guess it is a typo

Comment: oh thanks. Sorry for that, I'm kind of new to react :D

Answer (score 1):

The parent controls which children are displayed, so, when you remove one child, its state changes and then it needs to re-render the whole stuff.

The idea to optimize this, is to memoize the child component via [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).
React memo has a second parameter that is a function that tests if the component needs to re-render or not based on the props.

from the docs:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  /* render using props */
}
function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  /*
  return true if passing nextProps to render would return
  the same result as passing prevProps to render,
  otherwise return false
  */
}
export default React.memo(MyComponent, areEqual);
```

So, when you will remove a child, the parent is notified and re-renders its children, which will not be re-rendered unless you tell them to.

PS: Showing 900 children at once is not recommended, will the user see all of them ? may be you need to set a pagination so that displays only 10/20 children.

Comment: I don't actually get how to use the React.memo . But in the docs it's only used with functions. And my Literature component is a class component not a function. I've tried it like this: const Literature = React.memo(class extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {...
}
}) export default Literature 
but it still rerenders the entire page

Comment: Then you need to use [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) lifecycle method

Comment: not like this: `React.memo(class extends React` but rather `React.memo(ComponentType, areEqualFunc)`